# How do I use that haskell type system to describe relationships and thus prevent more mistakes

Tags: haskell, types

In this program, how can I use the type system to prevent imposter_d from type-checking so I can write functions where assumptions about relationships are checked. Here I have "accidentally" written imposter_d such that unrelated items are combined in error.

Is there some type-system feature (possibly with extra classes, data types, newtypes, etc) which I can use for construct and destruct so that Haskell will allow d and d' to typecheck and not imposter_d - perhaps based on some type parameter which, although its exact type cannot be known is known to be the same for b and c, or for b' and c', but cannot be known to be the same type for b and c'?

I want to avoid defining extra types for each place where I use construct - hence suspecting that universal quantification might be part of the solution.

```
module Foo where

import Control.Applicative

construct = id
destruct = id

tx = ZipList . reverse . getZipList

a = ZipList [1,2,3]
a' = tx a

b = construct a
c = (+1) <$> b
d = (-) <$> c <*> b
e = destruct d

-- same thing but for data in a different arrangement
b' = construct a'
c' = (+1) <$> b'
d' = (-) <$> c' <*> b'
e' = destruct d'

-- mixed the two arrangements together by mistake!!! oops, help me haskell!
imposter_d = (-) <$> c' <*> b
imposter_e = destruct imposter_d

main = do putStrLn $ show e
          putStrLn $ show e'
          putStrLn $ show imposter_e
```

e and e' are both ZipList [1, 1, 1] but imposter_e is different and I want to prevent myself from defining it by mistake. I appreciate that I might need a new type class for functor and applicative operations where correlating items are to be assumed.

Comment: Well how do you want to differentiate `b` and `b'`? If your operator was simply defined in terms of two values of the same type, it's enough to wrap them in different wrappers.

Comment: I've edited the comment to exclude that answer, I'm looking for something pretty generic that allows liberal usage with low boilerplate.

Comment: if i am not mistaken, you can define a customized functor, applicative wrapper which carries a type level tag, maybe something like `Symbol`, or `Nat`. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html is it what you want to do?

Comment: If construct and destruct are semantically the identity, what is to stop the user from just writing `construct ((-) <$> destruct c' <*> destruct b)` instead (that is, even if you find a way to get the type system to reject the given term)? If they are not semantically the identity, under which conditions may they not be used? If you want to have a type which is only accessible using its `Applicative` instance, all you need is a (abstract) type `newtype T s t a = T (t a)` and a function `t a -> (forall s . T s t a -> T s t b) -> t b` (but again, this adds no safety to your program).

Comment: HuStmpHrr, that's interesting. It might be an important part of the solution. Thanks.

Comment: user2407038, that would be okay with me. The goal is not to prevent the user from doing well-defined things if they've decided its right, but to make the correct thing by far the easiest and incorrect things less likely due to typos. However, I'd be interested in a solution that prohibits even more because it's highly instructive and such a solution can get the karma if it comes more than a couple of days before another solution. I'm not trying to restrict a thing to its applicative instance.

Comment: user2407038, to be clear, though, the newly constructed value couldn't be used with either c' or b in your example. So it still defines a group of related values.

Comment: You're gonna have to give a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve. In the case of `ZipList`s I can't think of any reason to prevent mixing and matching computations like that.

Comment: Benjamin Hodgson, This models games like "subtract the number you first thought of" with a single level of indirection allowing parallelism and problems with undefined results, etc, and allows symbolic computation instead of acting on lists, etc. It's a very generic thing that applies to problems that most programmers have solved in concrete ways in system programming, FRP, databases, etc. It's already unreasonably concrete.

Answer (score 0):

According to this comment:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279316/what-exactly-makes-the-haskell-type-system-so-revered-vs-say-java#comment605791_279362

> there's no way to have referential transparency and allow for analysis of self-referential graphs. If you can identify whether two references point to the same place then you are exactly violating referential transparency

Ie, by the fundamental principles by which Haskell was designed, one cannot do what I wanted to in this way.